# Manipulating legend text in R plotly

Tags: r, legend, plotly

I have a `data.frame` I'd like to scatter plot using `R`'s `plotly` with two factors which I'd like to color and shape by.

Here's my data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(12),y=rnorm(12),
                 group=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,3),rep(4,3)),
                 treatment=c(rep("A",6),rep("B",6)),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)

df$group <- factor(df$group,levels=1:4)
df$treatment <- factor(df$treatment,levels=c("A","B"))
```

Here's how I'm trying to plot:

```
require(plotly)

plot_ly(marker=list(size=10),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=~df$x,y=~df$y,color=~df$group,symbol=~df$treatment) %>% 
  add_annotations(text="group,treatment",xref="paper",yref="paper",x=1.02, xanchor="left",y=1.02,yanchor="top",legendtitle=TRUE,showarrow=FALSE) %>%
  layout(xaxis=list(title="x"),yaxis=list(title="y"))
```

which gives me:
[image]

Is it possible to get the text of `group` and `treatment` in the legend be separated by comma instead of the new line as it is now?

This means that instead of:

1

A

2

A

3

B

4

B

I'll have:

1,A

2,A

3,B

4,B

Answer (score 7):

Sounds trivial but it's one of the cases where `Plotly` decides whats *good* for you.

The legend labels are composed of the categories of `color` and `symbol` which are all passed in one command. In order to get control over the output, let's add each trace separately.

```
for (grou in groups) {
  for (treat in treatments) {
    trace_data <- subset(df, group == grou & treatment == treat)
    if (nrow(trace_data) > 0) {
      p <- add_trace(p,
                     x = trace_data$x,
                     y = trace_data$y,
                     marker = list(size = 10,
                                   color = group,
                                   symbol = as.integer(charToRaw(treat)) - 65),
                     type = 'scatter',
                     mode = "markers",
                     name = paste(grou, treat, sep = ",")
                     )
    }
  }
}
```

We pass the `color` (not strictly necessary) via `marker` and `symbol` also via `marker` (both can be passed in the `add_trace` command as well but then again `Plotly` decides for you what do to do with it).

The legend label is passed via `name`.

Note: You need to convert your treatment explicitly because symbol expects either a named symbol or a number (unless your treatments are named `diamond` or `circle`)

### [image]

**Complete code**

```
library(utils)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = rnorm(12),
                 y = rnorm(12),
                 group = c(rep(1, 3),
                           rep(2, 3),
                           rep(3, 3),
                           rep(4, 3)
                           ),
                 treatment=c(rep("A", 6),
                             rep("B", 6)
                             ),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE
                 )

groups <- unique(df$group)
treatments <- unique(df$treatment)

p <- plot_ly()
for (grou in groups) {
  for (treat in treatments) {
    trace_data <- subset(df, group == grou & treatment == treat)
    if (nrow(trace_data) > 0) {
      p <- add_trace(p,
                     x = trace_data$x,
                     y = trace_data$y,
                     marker = list(size = 10,
                                   color = group,
                                   symbol = as.integer(charToRaw(treat)) - 65),
                     type = 'scatter',
                     mode = "markers",
                     name = paste(grou, treat, sep = ",")
                     )
    }
  }
}
p <- add_annotations(p, 
                     text = "group,treatment",
                     xref = "paper",
                     yref = "paper",
                     x = 0.96, 
                     xanchor = "left",
                     y = 1.03,
                     yanchor = "top",
                     legendtitle = TRUE,
                     showarrow = FALSE) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "x"),
         yaxis = list(title = "y"))

p
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Maximilian Peters. What if df$group is a character rather an integer? I tried just defining df$group as.character() and can't reproduce your solution.

Comment: @dan: try removing `df$treatment <- factor(...` and it should also work for characters.

Comment: I just wrapped the group numbers in quotes in construction of df, in the code in your answer, and ran the rest of it. I the get an error: Error in add_trace(p, x = trace_data$x, y = trace_data$y, marker = list(size = 10,  : 
  object 'group' not found when running the plotly loop. If I change group to trace_data$group I don't get that error but I don't get two different colors anymore.

Comment: @dan: strange, tried quoting the numbers and it worked for me, which Plotly version are you using?

Comment: Just updated to the latest version from github: plotly_4.5.6.9000 and getting the same - the points are all colored in pink/orange but are separated by symbol=treatment