# R plot_ly pieplot legend with different column

Tags: r, plotly, legend, pie-chart

I have this data frame for buiding a pie plot with `plot_ly()` function:

```
piedat <- data.frame("phylum" = c("Non-classified genera", "Genera with RA < 1%", "Firmicutes", "Fibrobacteres", "Bacteroidetes", "Bacteroidetes"),
                     "genus" = c("Unclassified", "RA < 1%", "Clostridium", "Fibrobacter", "Bacteroides", "Prevotella"),
                     "sunra" = c(51.123358, 24.086378, 1.798356, 2.405086, 1.115162, 19.471660),
                     "col" = c("#F8766D", "#A3A500", "#00BF7D", "#00B0F6", "#E76BF3", "#E76BF3"))
```

I want the pie plot to represent the `sunra` abundances (they sum 100) using the `col` as color, the `genus` as labels and the `phylum` and `col` columns for the legend names and colour, respectively.
With this code I managed to do almost everything, as the legend still remains with `genus` names:

```
pie <- plot_ly(piedat) %>%
  add_trace(labels = ~genus, values = ~sunra, name = "phylum", type = 'pie', textposition = 'auto', sort = F, 
            textinfo = 'label+percent', textfont = list(size = 14), marker = list(line = list(width = 1))) %>% 
  layout(autosize = T, showlegend = T, colorway = piedat$col,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))
```

[image]

This is the legend I want:

[image]

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you'd like the labels to remain just like they are, and ***only*** change the text displayed in the legend. If that is the case, here's how you can get what you want without too much trouble:

---

Manipulating legend text i plotly can be [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43432881/manipulating-legend-text-in-r-plotly), so to keep things as simple as possible, leave the legend alone, and edit the labels instead. Just add another column to `piedat` consisting of `phylum` and `sunra`, change `labels = ~genus` to `labels = ~phylum`, change `textinfo = 'label+percent'` to `textinfo = 'text'` and include `text=~custom` in `add_trace()` to get:

[image]

**Complete code:**

```
piedat <- data.frame("phylum" = c("Non-classified genera", "Genera with RA < 1%", "Firmicutes", "Fibrobacteres", "Bacteroidetes", "Bacteroidetes"),
                     "genus" = c("Unclassified", "RA < 1%", "Clostridium", "Fibrobacter", "Bacteroides", "Prevotella"),
                     "sunra" = c(51.123358, 24.086378, 1.798356, 2.405086, 1.115162, 19.471660),
                     "col" = c("#F8766D", "#A3A500", "#00BF7D", "#00B0F6", "#E76BF3", "#E76BF3"))

piedat$custom <- paste(piedat$genus, format(piedat$sunra, digits=2))

pie <- plot_ly(piedat) %>%
  add_trace(labels = ~phylum, values = ~sunra, name = "phylum", type = 'pie', textposition = 'auto', sort = F, 
            textinfo = 'text', text=~custom, textfont = list(size = 14), marker = list(line = list(width = 1))) %>% 
  layout(autosize = T, showlegend = T, colorway = piedat$col,
         xaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE),
         yaxis = list(showgrid = FALSE, zeroline = FALSE, showticklabels = FALSE))

pie
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, if you have noticed, some info has been lost, i.e., the purple sector should be 2 sectors with Prevotella 19.5 and Bacteroides 1.1, but Prevotella sector has been lost, and the representation of Bacteroides is not real...

Comment: @ALG Ah, so the real issue here is that you'd like to show Bacteroides and Prevotella as differenet categoires in the chart, but show the two as one group in the legend?

Comment: That's it! Keep the chart as the original but group the legend corresponding to colors.

Comment: @ALG Not sure if it's doable. I'll have another look tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

A non-graphing solution would be to change the levels of your variable to be in the order you want them to appear.

```
piedata$phylum <- factor(piedata$phylum, levels=c("Non-classified genera", "Genera with RA < 1%", "Firmicutes", "Fibrobacteres", "Bacteroidetes")
```