# Add a legend to a plotly plot with drop-down menus in R

Tags: r, plotly

I have written the following code to produce a plotly plot with two drop-down menus.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# initial setup
iris.col <- factor(iris$Species, label = c("red", "blue", "green"))
iris.symbol <- factor(iris$Species, labels = c("diamond", "cross", "square"))

plot <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
                marker = list(color = alpha(as.character(iris.col), 0.2), 
                              symbol = ~iris.symbol, size = 8, 
                              line = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', width = 1)),
                type = "scatter", mode = "markers", text = ~Species,
                hovertemplate = paste('<i>Species</i>: %{text}',
                                      '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                                      '<b>Y</b>: %{y}'))

# X variable
x_var<-list(
  type = "list",
  x = 0.2,
  xanchor = "left",
  y = 1.2,
  buttons = list(
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(x = list(iris$Sepal.Length)),
                  list(xaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Length"))),
      label = "Sepal.Length"
    ),
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(x =list(iris$Sepal.Width)),
                  list(xaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Width"))),
      label = "Sepal.Width"
    ),
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(x = list(iris$Petal.Length)),
                  list(xaxis = list(title = "Petal.Length"))),
      label = "Petal.Length"
    ),
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(x = list(iris$Petal.Width)),
                  list(xaxis = list(title = "Petal.Width"))),
      label = "Petal.Width"
    )
  )
)

# Y variable
y_var<-list(
  type = "list",
  x = 0.8,
  xanchor = "left",
  y = 1.2,
  buttons = list(
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(y = list(iris$Sepal.Length)),
                  list(yaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Length"))),
      label = "Sepal.Length"
    ),
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(y =list(iris$Sepal.Width)),
                  list(yaxis = list(title = "Sepal.Width"))),
      label = "Sepal.Width"
    ),
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(y = list(iris$Petal.Length)),
                  list(yaxis = list(title = "Petal.Length"))),
      label = "Petal.Length"
    ),
    list(
      method = "update",
      args = list(list(y = list(iris$Petal.Width)),
                  list(yaxis = list(title = "Petal.Width"))),
      label = "Petal.Width"
    )
  )
)

# add layout
plot <- plot %>% layout(
  updatemenus = list(x_var,y_var),
  showlegend = TRUE,
  annotations = list(
    list(
      text = "<b>X-Axis:</b>", x=0.04, y=1.18, 
      xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
    ),
    list(
      text = "<b>Y-Axis:</b>", x=0.63, y=1.18, 
      xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
    )
  )
)
#make the plot
plot
```

I get this plot:
[image]

However, I was unable to add a legend to the plot based on Species.
I have tried this post [R+Plotly: Customize Legend Entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975912/rplotly-customize-legend-entries) which used `add_trace` to set up each legend class.

This method however made the colors of markers won't work anymore when I selected variables from the drop-down menus. Perhaps someone might have some solutions.

Answer (score 1):

##### Update

You identified that the axis titles weren't updating. By using `ifelse`, I dropped the axis title changes in my `btn` function.

Here's an update to that function. The titles now update as expected. The rest of the code and the explanation of the coding remain the same.

```
btn <- function(xLoc, m, nms, xOry) { # x btn position, method, names, x or y
  list(type = "list", x = xLoc, xanchor = "left", y = 1.2, 
       buttons = lapply(
         nms, function(k) {           # iterate over names
           if(xOry == "x") { # is this creating x or y btns?
             args = list(    # a list for each trace (each legend entry)
               list(x = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
               list(xaxis = list(title = k)))
           } else {
             args = list(    # a list for each trace (each legend 
               list(y = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
               list(yaxis = list(title = list(text = k))))
           }
           list(
             method = m, label = k, args = args)
       })
  )
}
```

###### All the code together

Here is all the code with the updated function.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# initial setup
iris.col <- factor(iris$Species, label = c("red", "blue", "green"))
iris.symbol <- factor(iris$Species, labels = c("diamond", "cross", "square"))

(plt <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
                split = ~Species,                                # <- I'm new
                marker = list(color = alpha(as.character(iris.col), 0.2), 
                              symbol = ~iris.symbol, size = 8, 
                              line = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', width = 1)),
                type = "scatter", mode = "markers", text = ~Species,
                hovertemplate = paste('<i>Species</i>: %{text}',
                                      '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                                      '<b>Y</b>: %{y}')))

ia <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[1],] # df for each species
ib <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[2],]
ic <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[3],]

btn <- function(xLoc, m, nms, xOry) { # x btn position, method, names, x or y
  list(type = "list", x = xLoc, xanchor = "left", y = 1.2, 
       buttons = lapply(
         nms, function(k) {           # iterate over names
           if(xOry == "x") { # is this creating x or y btns?
             args = list(    # a list for each trace (each legend entry)
               list(x = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
               list(xaxis = list(title = k)))
           } else {
             args = list(    # a list for each trace (each legend 
               list(y = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
               list(yaxis = list(title = list(text = k))))
           }
           list(
             method = m, label = k, args = args)
       })
  )
}

# add layout
plot2 <- plt %>% layout(
  updatemenus = list(btn(.2, "update", names(iris)[-5], "x"),  # <- I'm new
                     btn(.8, "update", names(iris)[-5], "y")), # <- I'm new
  showlegend = TRUE,
  annotations = list(
    list(
      text = "<b>X-Axis:</b>", x=0.04, y=1.18, 
      xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
    ),
    list(
      text = "<b>Y-Axis:</b>", x=0.63, y=1.18, 
      xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
    )
  )
)
#make the plot
plot2
```

[image]

---

---

##### Original Answer

When you separate by color, or in this case, you define a legend, Plotly splits the data into three different traces. When you sent the data through `update`, you sent one array of 150 values, where there were only 50 values before.

What you need is to define `x` and `y` for *each* trace.

Instead of the individualized button code that you've written which is pretty and really lengthy, I've written a function that does most of the work for me. In the `args` of this function:

1. the `ifelse`, is this creating buttons for x or y?
   (I used `setNames` initially, but Plotly just wasn't happy with all that noise, so `ifelse` it is.)
2. in `x =`  or `y =` , you'll notice *three* lists, that's one for each trace
3. for the layout update (the axis title), there is still only one list, because there is only one layout

###### The function and ancillary code to make it work:

```
ia <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[1],] # df for each species
ib <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[2],]
ic <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[3],]

btn <- function(xLoc, m, nms, xOry) { # btn pos, method, names, x or y?
  list(type = "list", x = xLoc, xanchor = "left", y = 1.2, # from original code 
       buttons = lapply(
         nms, function(k) {           # iterate over names
           list(
             method = m, label = k, 
             args = ifelse(           # is this creating x or y btns?
               xOry == "x", 
               list(   # data list for each trace (each legend entry)
                 list(x = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
                 list(xaxis = list(title = k))),
               list(
                 list(y = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
                 list(yaxis = list(title = k)))
               )
             )
         })
  )
}
```

###### The plot

This is nearly identical to your original code. The only difference is the argument `split = ~Species` and the wrap in parentheses.
**The parentheses allow you to create the object and render it at the same time.

```
(plt <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
                split = ~Species,                                # <- I'm new
                marker = list(color = alpha(as.character(iris.col), 0.2), 
                              symbol = ~iris.symbol, size = 8, 
                              line = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', width = 1)),
                type = "scatter", mode = "markers", text = ~Species,
                hovertemplate = paste('<i>Species</i>: %{text}',
                                      '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                                      '<b>Y</b>: %{y}')))
```

###### The layout

Last but not least, the `layout`. The only change is in the call for `updatemenus`, instead of the objects you initially created, `x_var` and `y_var`, I've called that function I created, `btn`.

The arguments call for the button placement on the x-axis, the method (`"update"`), the column names for the button labels, and whether it's the buttons for the `x` or the `y`.

```
# add layout
plot2 <- plt %>% layout( # btn pos, method, names, x or y?
  updatemenus = list(btn(.2, "update", names(iris)[-5], "x"),  # <- I'm new
                     btn(.8, "update", names(iris)[-5], "y")), # <- I'm new
  showlegend = TRUE,
  annotations = list(
    list(
      text = "<b>X-Axis:</b>", x=0.04, y=1.18, 
      xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow = FALSE
    ),
    list(
      text = "<b>Y-Axis:</b>", x=0.63, y=1.18, 
      xref = 'paper', yref = 'paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow = FALSE
    )
  )
)
```

[image]

[image]

###### All the code you've already seen

This is all the code in one chunk (easier copy + paste). It's everything you need to render the plot.

```
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

# initial setup
iris.col <- factor(iris$Species, label = c("red", "blue", "green"))
iris.symbol <- factor(iris$Species, labels = c("diamond", "cross", "square"))

(plt <- plot_ly(data = iris, x = ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, 
                split = ~Species,                                # <- I'm new
                marker = list(color = alpha(as.character(iris.col), 0.2), 
                              symbol = ~iris.symbol, size = 8, 
                              line = list(color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)', width = 1)),
                type = "scatter", mode = "markers", text = ~Species,
                hovertemplate = paste('<i>Species</i>: %{text}',
                                      '<br><b>X</b>: %{x}<br>',
                                      '<b>Y</b>: %{y}')))

ia <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[1],] # df for each species
ib <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[2],]
ic <- iris[iris$Species == levels(iris$Species)[3],]

btn <- function(xLoc, m, nms, xOry) { # x btn position, method, names, x or y
  list(type = "list", x = xLoc, xanchor = "left", y = 1.2, 
       buttons = lapply(
         nms, function(k) {           # iterate over names
           list(
             method = m, label = k,
             args = ifelse(           # is this creating x or y btns?
               xOry == "x", 
               list(   # a list for each trace (each legend entry)
                 list(x = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
                 list(xaxis = list(title = k))),
               list(
                 list(y = list(ia[, k], ib[, k], ic[, k])),  # 3 lists, 3 traces
                 list(yaxis = list(title = k)))
             )
           )
         })
  )
}

# add layout
plot2 <- plt %>% layout(
  updatemenus = list(btn(.2, "update", names(iris)[-5], "x"),  # <- I'm new
                     btn(.8, "update", names(iris)[-5], "y")), # <- I'm new
  showlegend = TRUE,
  annotations = list(
    list(
      text = "<b>X-Axis:</b>", x=0.04, y=1.18, 
      xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
    ),
    list(
      text = "<b>Y-Axis:</b>", x=0.63, y=1.18, 
      xref='paper', yref='paper',xanchor = "left", showarrow=FALSE
    )
  )
)
#make the plot
plot2
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. The only slight problem is the titles for X and Y axes will not be automatically updated. The second figure you attached has Petal.Length selected as X axis, but the title of X axis is still Sepal.Length.

Comment: Sorry about that! I've found the issue and updated my answer.

Comment: yes, the problem solved. I really appreciate it.